# how do you merge two data frames on two common columns and fill empty cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames df1 and df2, I need to join them based on server and row columns (both df1 and df2 have the same server, row), final_df need to have data from both df1 and df2 where grid =available need to be inserted into the  final_df with row and slot numbers. Final_df should not have empty cells. Once new grid and slot numbers inserted to the final_df, all the other columns values should the same as the last row for that server.Final df need to be sorted by server and slot (slot going from 1, 2, 3, etc)

```
df1



Env location lob      grid row server        model        make          slot
Prod USA     Market   AB3 bc2  Server123     Hitachi        dcs           1
Prod USA     Market   AB3 bc2  Server123     Hitachi        dcs           2
Prod USA     Market   AB3 bc2  Server123     Hitachi        dcs           3
Prod USA     Market   AB3 bc2  Server123     Hitachi       dcs            4
Dev  EMEA    Ins      AB6 bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc            3
Dev  EMEA    Ins      AB6 bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc            3
Dev  EMEA    Ins      AB6 bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc            3
Dev  EMEA    Ins      AB6 bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc            4
Dev  EMEA    Ins      AB6 bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc            5
Dev  EMEA    Ins      AB6 bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc            5
Dev  EMEA    Ins      AB6 bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc            6
UAT  PAC     Retail   AB6 bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           3
UAT  PAC     Retail   BB6 bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           4
UAT  PAC     Retail   BB6 bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           5
UAT  PAC     Retail   BB6 bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           6
```

and

```
df2

grid      row  server       slot
AB3       bc2  Server123     1
AB3       bc2  Server123     2
AB3       bc2  Server123     3
AB3       bc2  Server123     4
AB6       bc4  Serverabc     3
AB6       bc4  Serverabc     4
AB6       bc4  Serverabc     5
AB6       bc4  Serverabc     6
available bc4  Serverabc     7
available bc4  Serverabc     8
available bc4  Serverabc     9
available bc4  Serverabc     10
AB6     bc4    Serverzzz     3
BB6     bc4    Serverzzz     4
BB6     bc4    Serverzzz     5
BB6     bc4    Serverzzz     6
available bc4  Serverzzz     7
available bc4  Serverzzz     8
```

final_df need to be like this:

```
Env location lob    grid      row    server        model       make        slot
Prod USA     Market AB3       bc2  Server123     Hitachi        dcs           1
Prod USA     Market AB3       bc2  Server123     Hitachi        dcs           2
Prod USA     Market AB3       bc2  Server123     Hitachi        dcs           3
Prod USA     Market AB3       bc2  Server123     Hitachi.       dcs           4
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6       bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           3
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6       bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           4
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6       bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           5
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6       bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           6
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   available bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           7
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   available bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           8
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   available bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           9
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   available bc4  Serverabc     IBM            abc           10
UAT  PAC     Retail   AB6     bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           3
UAT  PAC     Retail   BB6     bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           4
UAT  PAC     Retail   BB6     bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           5
UAT  PAC     Retail   BB6     bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust           6
UAT  PAC     Retail  available bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust          7
UAT  PAC     Retail  available bc4  Serverzzz     Cisco          ust          8
```

I tried this:

```
final_df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["server", "row"], how=outer)
```

I am getting empty cells. any ideas how can I merge 2 data frames without having any empty cells?

Comment: There is no `model` column in `df2`

Comment: The last line `final_df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["server", "row", how=outer)` generate syntax error. It seems to be incomplete.

Comment: You say _where grid = available_ but then your merge doesn't attempt that, and your output data don't seem to match that either. Why?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
available_groups_from_df2 = {}
for i, g in df2.groupby(["server", "row"]):
    if "available" in g["grid"].values:
        available_groups_from_df2[i] = g

out = []
cols = ["Env", "location", "lob", "model", "make"]
for i, g in df1.groupby(["server", "row"]):
    if i in available_groups_from_df2:
        out.append(available_groups_from_df2[i])
        out[-1][cols] = g[cols].iloc[0]
    else:
        out.append(g)

out = pd.concat(out)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
     Env location     lob       grid  row     server    model make  slot
0   Prod      USA  Market        AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  dcs     1
1   Prod      USA  Market        AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  dcs     2
2   Prod      USA  Market        AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  dcs     3
3   Prod      USA  Market        AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  dcs     4
4    Dev     EMEA     Ins        AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc     3
5    Dev     EMEA     Ins        AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc     4
6    Dev     EMEA     Ins        AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc     5
7    Dev     EMEA     Ins        AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc     6
8    Dev     EMEA     Ins  available  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc     7
9    Dev     EMEA     Ins  available  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc     8
10   Dev     EMEA     Ins  available  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc     9
11   Dev     EMEA     Ins  available  bc4  Serverabc      IBM  abc    10
12   UAT      PAC  Retail        AB6  bc4  Serverzzz    Cisco  ust     3
13   UAT      PAC  Retail        BB6  bc4  Serverzzz    Cisco  ust     4
14   UAT      PAC  Retail        BB6  bc4  Serverzzz    Cisco  ust     5
15   UAT      PAC  Retail        BB6  bc4  Serverzzz    Cisco  ust     6
16   UAT      PAC  Retail  available  bc4  Serverzzz    Cisco  ust     7
17   UAT      PAC  Retail  available  bc4  Serverzzz    Cisco  ust     8
```

Comment: this line (cols = ["Env", "location", "lob", "model", "make"]) is the name of the columns not in df2 but in df1?

Comment: @user1471980 Yes, these are column names from `df1` (they don't exist in `df2`, without them, the values in these columns will be `NaN` in final dataframe)

Comment: I am getting KeyError: None of the [Index (columns names are in the [columns] error

Comment: is there way to not include the column names?